# How to strip unicode chars (LEFT_TO_RIGHT_MARK) from a string in php

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I'm trying to remove LEFT-TO-RIGHT-MARK (\u200e) and RIGHT-TO-LEFT-MARK (\u200f) from a string before encoding it as JSON. Neither of the following seems to work:

```
$s = mb_ereg_replace("\u200e", '', $s);
$s = preg_replace("#\u200e#u", '', $s);
$s = preg_replace("#\u200e#", '', $s);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which encoding is the string in?

Answer (score 14):

After wrestling with this issue for a couple of days, I finally have found the answer!

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\x{200e}|\x{200f})/u', '', $str);
```

Comment: worked for me where @tmont's answer (With higher votes) didn't

Answer (score 8):

Your Unicode escaping is wrong, this should work:

```
preg_replace('/\x20(\x0e|\x0f)/', '', $string)
```

Test:

```
<?php
  $string = chr(0x20) . chr(0x0e) . 'fo' . chr(0x20) . chr(0x0e) . 'o' . chr(0x20) . chr(0x0f);
  echo $string . "\n";
  echo preg_replace('/\x20(\x0e|\x0f)/', '', $string);
?>
```

Or, use `str_replace()`:

```
  str_replace(array("\x20\x0e", "\x20\x0f"), '', $string);
```

Comment: actually, it does work. my test was ill conceived. updated answer to include str_replace(). could probably use strtr() as well.

Comment: What exactly is \x0e?

Comment: @iankit `\x0e` is the regex equivalent of `chr(0x20)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encoding your script file in UTF-8, and actually typing (or copy+pasting) the characters in there?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `str_replace`, and coding that character using it's character codes ; something like this, maybe :

```
$new_string = str_replace("\x20\x0f", "", $your_string);
```

And, in your case, as you have several different characters to replace, you might replace them all in one call to `str_replace` :

```
$new_string = str_replace(
    array(
        "\x20\x0e", 
        "\x20\x0f", 
    ),
    array(
        "", 
        "", 
    ),
    $your_string
);
```

Does it work for your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? its utf8 encoding of 200e and 200f

```
$s=preg_replace('/\xe2\x80[\x8e\x8f]/', '', $s)
```

or with str_replace

```
$s=str_replace("\xe2\x80\x8e", "", $s);
$s=str_replace("\xe2\x80\x8f", "", $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
preg_replace('/\x{E2}\x{80}\x{8E}/', '', $s); 
// strip unicode chars (LEFT_TO_RIGHT_MARK)
```