# Cannot get array element by key, but key exists on array

Tags: php, drupal-8, drupal-fields

I'm working with Drupal 8, but since this looks like a PHP problem to me, I'm asking it here and not on Drupal Answers.

The `isset` statement in the following code should return `TRUE`, but it does not:

```
/*
$specifier = 'field_google_hire_identifier‎'
$field_storage_definitions = array of objects
*/

var_dump(
  isset($field_storage_definitions[$specifier]),
  $specifier,
  $field_storage_definitions[$specifier],
  $field_storage_definitions
);
die;
```

**Output on the screen:**
[image: var_dump() output]
*Other array elements...*
[image: var_dump() output]
*Other array elements...*

Original output HTML: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZwRJdR

**Array keys:**

```
var_dump( array_keys($field_storage_definitions));
```

**Output on the screen:**
[image: array keys]

I'm kind of clueless why `isset($field_storage_definitions[$specifier]` is `FALSE` and `$field_storage_definitions[$specifier]` is `NULL`

I uninstalled APC and disabled Opcache.

Comment: `$field_storage_definitions[$specifier]` is NULL - is it unexpected ?

Comment: whish key you need to access ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed yes, it should be a Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig object, as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI the 'field_google_hire_identifier‎' key

Comment: @Orlando, can't `$field_storage_definitions[$specifier]` be Null  any way ?

Comment: the "field_google_hire_identifier" is an object , and this object have protected value , to get those properties , use reflection , wanna see an example if that what you are looking for

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI yes, it's an object, but I don't want to get any values from it. I only want to get the object.

Comment: @Orlando, how do you get the value of `$field_storage_definitions[$specifier]` ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed I just use var_dump($field_storage_definitions[$specifier]);

Comment: @Orlando, but how do you get the value of `$field_storage_definitions[$specifier]` ? Where does the value of `$field_storage_definitions` come from ?

Comment: try with :$field_storage_definitions->{$specifier}

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed $field_storage_definitions is an array generated by Drupal: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityManager.php/function/EntityManager%3A%3AgetFieldStorageDefinitions/8.6.x
But it looks like a valid array, so I don't think theres the problem.

Comment: @Orlando, what is the full value of `$field_storage_definitions`?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI $field_storage_definitions->{$specifier} is NULL

Comment: @Orlando try run var_dump( array_keys($field_storage_definitions));

Comment: @MuhammadAzizolAminuddin I've added it to the question. There is a 'field_google_hire_identifier‎' array key. But for some reason, it seems like it does not exist.

Comment: Please check the **real** content of  `$specifier` - according to the first dump of that variable, it contains a string with 31 characters, while the string `field_google_hire_identifier` obviously contains only 28 characters

Comment: @NicoHaase oh, yes. That's a good point. But how can I get the real content of it? Shouldn't var_dump() return the real content?

Comment: Well, where does it come from? Could it contain spaces, tabulators, line feeds,...?

Comment: @NicoHaase It is passed a method argument: $nodesNotOnSourceEntityQuery->condition('field_google_hire_identifier‎', $sourceIds, 'NOT IN');

Comment: @NicoHaase executing the following `var_dump($specifier, 'field_google_hire_identifier‎');` returns:

/app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php:102:string 'field_google_hire_identifier‎' (length=31)
/app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Query/Sql/Tables.php:102:string 'field_google_hire_identifier‎' (length=31)

which is very odd, since 'field_google_hire_identifier‎' only has 28 characters

Comment: Have you checked whether there are any hidden chars that a `var_dump` would not show?

Comment: There is a [https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm](right to left mark) at the end of the string: `var_dump($specifier, json_encode('field_google_hire_identifier‎'), preg_replace('/\p{C}+/u', "", 'field_google_hire_identifier‎'));`

Output: 
string 'field_google_hire_identifier‎' (length=31)
string '"field_google_hire_identifier\u200e"' (length=36)
string 'field_google_hire_identifier' (length=28)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130740/determining-and-removing-invisible-characters-from-a-string-in-php-e2808e](It is removed using this)

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks a lot for your help. Now I know what the problem is, and what to look out for. The input string is fine, but somewhere on the way the right to left mark is added. Have to dig into it where this happens. But that is outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [right to left mark](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm) at the end of the string that was used to select the array key. Since the string and the array key were not the same, the array key could not be retrieved.

The left to right mark can be removed using

```
preg_replace('/\p{C}+/u', "", $string)
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23131396/6653862

You can check if a string contains invisible characters by using

```
json_encode($string)
```

Comment: Good that you've shared this insight!

Answer (score -3):

If I were you, I would try this:

```
$true_Array = (Array)$array_With_Object;
```

Comment: Do you have any explanation for that?

Comment: This produces the same output, the $field_storage_definitions variable already is an array.